# How to solve 'ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined'

Tags: sql, oracle

Question :. For each book that is loaned out from the "Branch_C" branch and whose DueDate
is 02-Apr-13, retrieve the book title, the borrower's name, and the borrower's
address.

my answer ::

```
select TITTLE , NAME, ADDRESS 
    from BOOK B , BORROWER O, BOOK_LOANS L  
    where B.BOOKID= L.BOOKID and L.BRANCHID = 
        (select BRANCHID from LIBRARY_BRANCH where BRANCHNAME='Branch_C')
        and (O.CRADNO=L.CRADNO) and L.DUE_DATE='2013-2-13'
```

l have this error

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: It means 1 or more of your selected columns appears in more than 1 of your selected tables. Amend your selected columns to include the alias of the table you wish to select the column from.

Comment: I remove mysql tag as your question is abput oracle ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should define columns belongs which table

```
select B.TITTLE , O.NAME, L.ADDRESS 
    from BOOK B , BORROWER O, BOOK_LOANS L  
    where B.BOOKID= L.BOOKID and L.BRANCHID = 
        (select BRANCHID from LIBRARY_BRANCH where BRANCHNAME='Branch_C')
        and (O.CRADNO=L.CRADNO) and L.DUE_DATE='2013-2-13'
```

Comment: Can we really assume `ADDRESS` is in `BOOK_LOANS`, and not the `BORROWER` address? Also `BRANCHNAME` needs a table name prefix too, just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a column in your query that is defined in more than one table with the same name. Prefix the fields with the table name.

```
select table_a.ambiguos_name, table_b.ambiguos_name
from table_a inner join table_b on table_a.id = table_b.id
```

Answer (score -1):

*"whose DueDate is 02-Apr-13"*

well, then the date should be like 
L.DUE_DATE='2013-04-02'

Comment: this does not solve the problem ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
but the date in the WHERE clause is indeed not correct

Comment: yes, as you can see, the problem has already been solved in the topic. still the proposed solutions fail to satisfy the

Comment: "whose DueDate is 02-Apr-13"